EF Core 8 Code First Migration Missing Default Values
I am working on a .NET 7 project with EF Core 8 and attempting to use code first migrations with Microsoft SQL Server, but for some reason I can't get any default values to generate in the migrations.
Model:
public class Test
    {
        public int TestId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set;  }
    }
}

Configuration:
public class TestConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Test>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Test> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("Test", "dbo");
        builder.HasKey(x => x.TestId).HasName("PK_Test").IsClustered();

        builder.Property(x => x.TestId).ValueGeneratedOnAdd().UseIdentityColumn();
        builder.Property(x => x.Name).HasDefaultValue("TestValue");
    }
}

DB Context:
public class TdeContext : DbContext
{
    public TdeContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options) { }

    public DbSet<Test> Tests { get; set; }
}

When I use Add-Migration TestMigration given the above classes, the generated migration does not include any defaultValue specification:
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
        name: "Tests",
        columns: table => new
        {
            TestId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
                .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
            Name = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: false)
        },
        constraints: table =>
        {
            table.PrimaryKey("PK_Tests", x => x.TestId);
        });
}

protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    migrationBuilder.DropTable(
        name: "Tests");
}

I would expect the code to look like Name = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: false, defaultValue: "TestValue")
Can someone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Turns out my Fluent configuration was not being applied at all.  Needed to add the following code to TdeContext:
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new TestConfiguration());
}

Now the migration is as expected.
(You know how it goes.  You beat your head against a wall for a day and finally post a question to SO, only to figure it out five minutes afterwards.)
